# Matplotlib Heatmap with X, Y data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap

I want to make a heatmap in `matplotlib` using either `pcolor` or another heatmap library. I have found many great examples, but can't determine how to either get my data in the correct format or instead plot using the format my data is in.

Here is how my data is set up

```
X  Y  Value
0  1  .6
0  2  .3
0  3  .2
1  1  .8
1  2  .4
1  3  .9
```

Thus, the `X` and `Y` columns denote `(X,Y)` pairs where `Value` is the value of the corresponding cell. I am struggling to find a way to either transform the data to work with `pcolor` or another method of plotting. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This link from the official doc provides a nice example: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look like you use pandas dataframe.
Before plotting pivot dataframe to be a table and use heatmap method, i.e. from seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_clipboard()
table = df.pivot('Y', 'X', 'Value')
ax = sns.heatmap(table)
ax.invert_yaxis()
print(table)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Output:

```
X    0    1
Y
1  0.6  0.8
2  0.3  0.4
3  0.2  0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn your x & y values into a 2D numpy array. The two dimensions of the array represent x & y, while the values are mapped to the heatmap colourbar. More colour maps are given [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import matplotlib.cm as cmap

m = np.array([[.6, .3, .2], [.8, .4, .9]])
mpl.imshow(m, cmap=cmap.hot)
mpl.colorbar()
mpl.show()
```

produces
[image: heatmap example]

Comment: You do not have `x,y ` relation in your code, you got 2d matrix, with values inside, image is generated based on values you provided, they are all indexed upto 3, with some `-half` offset

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but here's a solution to OP's question using only `matplotlib`, as was requested. It relies on using `imshow`'s `extent` option to do the job. For more info, see the [matplotlib manual](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xvals = [0,1]
yvals = [1,3]

zvals = [[0.6, 0.3, 0.2], [0.8, 0.4, 0.9]]

heatmap, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(zvals,cmap='inferno',extent=[xvals[0],xvals[1],yvals[0],yvals[1]],interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',aspect='auto')
ax.set(xlabel='some x', ylabel='some y')

cbar = heatmap.colorbar(im)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('stuff')

heatmap.savefig('heatmap.png')
```

which results in the following image

[image: heatmap with specified x-values, y-values, and density data]